# Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in a multiple script aggregations elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, aggregate

I'm trying to build a query allowing me to make multiple aggregations on a single query. Here's the request I'm sending :

```
 {
    "size": 1,
    "aggs": {
        "firmNames": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "firm_name",
                "size": 100000000
            },
            "aggs": {
                "domains": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "domain",
                        "size": 100000000
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "logDates": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "log_date",
                                "size": 10000000
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                                "traffics": {
                                    "sum": {
                                        "field": "traffic"
                                    }
                                },
                                "script_fields": {
                                    "scripted_metric": {
                                        "script": {
                                            "lang": "painless",
                                            "inline": "HashSet set = new HashSet; set.add(doc['file_name']); return set;"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
```

However, I'm getting the following error when executing this query :

```
   {
      "error" : {`enter code here`
        "root_cause" : [
          {
            "type" : "parsing_exception",
            "reason" : "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [script_fields]: [script].",
            "line" : 15,
            "col" : 23
          }
        ],
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [script_fields]: [script].",
        "line" : 15,
        "col" : 23
      },
      "status" : 400
    }
```

I've been trying to change this query in many forms to make it works but I always end up with this error.

Answer (score 2):

The `script_fields` section is not at the right place, it should be located at the top level:

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "aggs": {
    "firmNames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "firm_name",
        "size": 100000000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "domains": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "domain",
            "size": 100000000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "logDates": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "log_date",
                "size": 10000000
              },
              "aggs": {
                "traffics": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "traffic"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "scripted_metric": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "HashSet set = new HashSet(); set.add(doc.file_name.value); return set;"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have change the request,but I get another error:
        "script_stack" : [
          "... w HashSet(); set.add(doc[file_name]); return set;",
          "                             ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "HashSet set = new HashSet(); set.add(doc[file_name]); return set;",

Comment: "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Variable [file_name] is not defined."
      }


but the file_name at the doc filed have  defined

Comment: Please show your mapping and a sample document with a `file_name` field.

Comment: the mapping is:

Comment: the mapping  is:
"bandwidth" : {"_all" : {"enabled" : false}, { "string fields" : {"match" : "*","match_mapping_type" : "string", "mapping" : { "doc_values" : true,"index" : "not_analyzed","omit_norms" : true,"type" : "keyword"}}} ],
        "properties" : { "domain" : {"type" : "keyword"}, "file_name" : {"type" : "keyword" }, "firm_name" : {"type" : "keyword" }, "from_time" : { "type" : "double" }, "log_date" : {"type" : "date"},"traffic" : { "type" : "double"} } }

Comment: Please update your question, it will be more legible

Comment: My purpose is to transform from sql:
select concat_ws(':',collect_set(file_name)),id as file_name from tableName group by id to elasticsearch rest  grammar